# Spring MongoDB find sets annotated id field as null

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am using `spring-data-mongodb` to persist my Java objects to MongoDB. Everthing works fine except one specific operation:

```
 @Override
 public Collection<MyDocument> findAllByTags(Collection<String> tags) {
        FindIterable<MyDocument> results = operations.getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME)
                .find(Filters.all(FIELD_TAGS, tags), MyDocument.class);
        return StreamSupport.stream(results.spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList());
 }
```

The document class looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Document
public class MyDocument implements MyEntity {


    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @BsonProperty("myId")
    private String myId;

    @BsonProperty("dateCreated")
    private Date dateCreated;

    @BsonProperty("otherField")
    private String otherField;

    @Indexed
    @BsonProperty("tags")
    private Collection<String> tags;

    //more fields
```

All fields of all objects are returned as expected except for the one annotated with `@Id` which is set to **null**. Does anyone know what is causing this behaviour and how to fix it? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working as follows:

```
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
 @Document
 public class MyDocument implements MyEntity {
    
    
    @MongoId(value = FieldType.STRING)
    private String myId;

   //...
```

And the query:

```
 @Override
 public Collection<MyDocument> findAllByTags(Collection<String> tags) {
     return operations.find(query(Criteria.where(FIELD_TAGS).all(tags)), MyDocument.class);
 }
```